# How to model a conditional demand forecast model as ex-ante forecast for a moving population?

Tags: time-series, regression, predictive-modeling, forecasting, forecast

Goal: I am trying to forecast demand from a specific population given a specific promotion on a certain period of time frame.

The data is of the format:

> date | promotion % | sales in 1000s(y)
>
> 01-Jan | 20 | 10
>
> 02-Jan | 25 | 12
>
> ...
>
> 01-Oct | 23 | 130

Now given that demand at any given point of time `t` depends on time `t-1`, I tried to model this as time series model ,and to capture the impact of promotion, I would add an exogenous variable w/ promotion.

So, this would typically be modelled as an ex-ante forecast.

The problem starts when population to whom the promotion is offered has to bear a specific criteria(say # of transactions > 2 ). And there are new customers acquired daily, who might or might not bear that specific criteria.

In summary,
if I look back from 1st-OCT , I have 1000 customers with # of transactions > 2.

The demand generated over time from these folks would look like:

> date | promotion % |  # of customers causing demand | sales in 1000s(y)
>
> 01-Jan | 20 | 100 | 10
>
> 02-Jan | 25 | 150 | 12
>
> ...
>
> 01-Oct | 23 | 1000 | 130

Now the forecast needs to be on these 1000 customers only for different promotion values in coming days (02-Oct, 03-Oct,...,07-Oct) i.e.

Forecast for:

> date | promotion % |  # of customers causing demand | sales in 1000s(y)
>
> 02-Oct | 20 | 1000 | ?
>
> 02-Oct | 30 | 1000 | ?
>
> 03- Oct| 20 | 1000 | ?
>
> 03- Oct| 30 | 1000 | ?

**Problem:**

Given, that I am tracking demand generated only due to the folks that I have information so far(1000 customers), in the validation period, the demand curve changes, and does not have the trend and seasonality components as before. This can be seen below:

[image]

I went thru https://otexts.com/fpp2/forecasting-regression.html, and the solution that came to mind was to be able to predict the number of customers(prediction of predictors) and to translate this into pure ex-ante forecast problem.

But the forecast of predictors(# of customers) is difficult and I would want to avoid a convoluted design as far as I can.

Another way would be to model this as a regression problem, w/ addition of lag variables as features.

I also researched a couple of research papers but so far there is no obvious way of modelling this, or I have limited terminology with me to be able to find this.

**The actual question:**

Is there a way to model time series for a growing population causing demand and do a conditional forecast?